# Google Place Request_Denied Horror

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api

i want to use Google Places API but i keep getting a Request_Denied. i entered to the Google API Console, turned on google places API. my code goes like this:

```
    NSString *searchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Beirut"];
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=%@&sensor=true&key=%@!",searchString, kGOOGLE_API_KEY];

    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:(requestURL)];

    //response
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
    NSDictionary *locationResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

    NSLog(@"%@",locationResults);
```

i doubled checked that i'm using the correct API key and i receive this output:

```
{
    "debug_info" =     (
    );
    "html_attributions" =     (
    );
    results =     (
    );
    status = "REQUEST_DENIED";
}
```

i entered again to the Google API console and clicked on "Try" through the  "question mark" info button next to the Google Places on/off switch and i was direct to another tab having the same output. how can i solve this?

Edit: multi-type added to URL causes an error

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=%@&types=food|bar&sensor=true&key=%@", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", 1000], kGOOGLE_API_KEY];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an ! at the end of the urlString.  I deleted it, tested the code and it returns the results

```
    NSString *searchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"NewYork"];
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=%@&sensor=true&key=%@",searchString, kGOOGLE_API_KEY];

    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:requestURL];

    //response
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    if(response){
        NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
        NSDictionary *locationResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

        NSLog(@"%@",locationResults);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"nil");
    }
```

Comment: *face palm* my bad.. it's working now but when i include to types such as food|bar in the url, it stops working (app crashes) at the NSDictionary part. any hint why is this happening?

Comment: Post the NSDictionary part of the code and the error.   If response is nil it might crash.

Comment: please refer above for the code. and yes it's returning nil. what could cause this?

Comment: Try to see the error.  Create NSError variable before the response set in the response and NSLog it when response is nil. I will look into it later on today. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: solved this problem by adding this:
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=%@&types=food|hospital&sensor=true&key=%@", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", 1000], kGOOGLE_API_KEY];//|bar|cafe|casino|gym|amusement_park|night_club|park|restaurant|shopping_mall|stadium
    urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

but why i should add this?

Comment: As far as i understand you have spaces in the url and to create a valid url you have to add escapes for special characters and spaces.  From apple docs: stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: Returns a representation of the receiver using a given encoding to determine the percent escapes necessary to convert the receiver into a legal URL string.

Comment: ya and i was told that i'm using the pipe thing "|" in the Types field which requires me to use percent-encoding. thank you :)